# OOM Killer: Processes have a score of over a 1000

Tags: linux, memory, proc, out-of-memory

All top links when Googling for OOM score seem to indicate that the values must be between -1000 and 1000.

I tried to verify that with a simple `cat /proc/*/oom_score | sort -n | less` and I encountered all sorts of values ranging from 0 to 30132501, with the vast majority being between 1000 and 10000.

How should I interpret this?

To my knowledge nothing is manually adjusting the `oom_score` files.

System information:

```
%uname -a
Linux hhgw16 2.6.18-371.el5 #1 SMP Tue Oct 1 08:35:08 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

% lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
Release:        5.10
Codename:       Final
```

Comment: Could it be that this rule only applies for the newer version of the OOM killer (as outlined [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/391222/)) and since this is an older version of the kernel (`2.6.18 < 2.6.36`) the rules are different?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably just a historical weirdness in that old kernel. I just tried with my kernel (similar to vanilla version 5.4.124) and got results like this:

```
$ cat /proc/*/oom_score | sort -n | uniq -c
    274 0
      9 1
      2 2
      1 3
      2 4
      1 5
      1 10
      2 17
      1 20
      1 37
      1 42
      3 200
      1 201
      1 202
      1 205
      1 212
      4 300
     11 301
     16 302
     24 303
      3 304
      3 305
      1 306
      1 310
      1 313
```

(The first column is count of processes having this value and the second column is the `oom_score` value, as you can see my system doesn't go over 1000.)